# How to import declared global variable in typescript using webpack

Tags: typescript, webpack, es6-modules

I am having trouble importing declared global variable.

On our website, we have third party framework, which integrates only using  tag and creates global variable on window for example `window.thirdParty`. So usage is like: `thirdParty.methodOne()`
I wrote definition file third-party.d.ts which is like this:

```js
import { ITrirdPartyFramework } from './third-party-definitions/third-party-framework';

export interface ITrirdPartyFramework {
   methodOne():void,
}
```

then i have a file (global-variables.ts), which defines global variables:

```js
export declare const thirdParty: ITrirdPartyFramework;
```

and finally i want to use it in my modules:

```
import { thirdParty } from './global-variables';

export const myFunction = () => {
    thirdParty.methodOne();
}
```

Problem is that webpack compiles the definitions as regular modules and on runtime i get error, because compiled code looks like this:

```
_global_variables__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__["thirdParty"].methodOne();
```

instead of

```
thirdParty.methodOne();
```

Do you know, how to tell webpack to ignore the definitions or how to deal with this situation ?

Comment: define your globals in *.d.ts file

Comment: Thanks for tip, i tried it but webpack doesnt compile, it cant find the module: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './global-variables' in 'my-code-file.ts'.

Comment: You don't have to import *.d.ts files,  they are globally visible.
You can keep only type definitions in those files, but not implementation

Comment: 1. Rename global-variables.ts to global-variables.d.ts. 2. remove export keyword from global-variables. 3. remove line "import { thirdParty } from './global-variables';"

Comment: Thanks a lot @Artem, it really solved my problem. 
But i cant accept comment as answer. If you want, you can post the answer and i will accept it, or i am going to rewrite you answer tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to import *.d.ts files, they are globally visible.
You can keep only type definitions in those files, but not implementation

Next steps will solve your problem:

1. Rename **global-variables.ts** to **global-variables.d.ts**
2. remove `export` keyword from **global-variables.d.ts**
3. remove line `import { thirdParty } from './global-variables';`